# UITableViewController estimatedRowHeight with detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Quick question: I have a `UITableViewController`, the general setup works fine. 
I am just trying to fine-tuning the spacing.

In the `UITableViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` I call:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
```

Some of my default cells use the `detailTextLabel` (`style: .subtitle`) and some don't (`style: .default`). 
When they do, the cells do not seem to adjust the row height.
The text looks crammed, especially when the `detailTextLabel` is two lines.

I wanted to avoid having to override the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` function?
Is there a trick?

Thanks

Comment: Any quick screens of what's happening? :)

Comment: instead of using the height property method try same with height delegate method. Bcz delegate method calls for each cell, so you can set different height for each cell.

Comment: Use constraints. and delegate method.

Comment: Check this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: Why you don't want to ovverride this? tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Because I can't calculate the height. The content is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default behavior of the system cell. If you expect another output, just create your custom cell, and give top and bottom constraints as you like. Good luck ;)

Comment: I tried this, but when I set the `topAnchor` and `bottomAnchor` the labels moved, but the cell height did not change.

Comment: What customizations did you do to the cell? With custom cell I meant, cell with your own labels, and constraints set to both labels. When there are correct constraints, cell is resized correctly.

Comment: ok - so I shouldn't use `self.textLabel` and `self.detailTextLabel` in my custom UITableViewCell?

Comment: Yep, just add 2 labels in storyboard or nib, setup font, number of lines etc, and add constraints to them.

Comment: I'm not using storyboards. I tried to get away with it by using the default labels. (see edit above) Will try it with custom labels.

Comment: It does not work when you try to manipulate the standard labels. You must create custom labels. Then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue which you faced and I got one best answer. I added constraint programatically and its will work for me. Hope it will help to solve your issue.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *cellConstraint in self.constraints) {
        [self removeConstraint:cellConstraint];
        id first_object = cellConstraint.first_object == self ? self.contentView : cellConstraint.first_object;
        id seccondItem = cellConstraint.second_object == self ? self.contentView : cellConstraint.second_object;
        NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewConstraint =
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:first_object
                                 attribute:cellConstraint.firstAttribute
                                 relatedBy:cellConstraint.relation
                                    toItem:seccondItem
                                 attribute:cellConstraint.secondAttribute
                                multiplier:cellConstraint.multiplier
                                  constant:cellConstraint.constant];
        [self.contentView addConstraint:contentViewConstraint];
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe I need to remove existing constraints. Will try that first.

Comment: Let me know if removing constraints will work for you or not.

Comment: Can you interchange the value code for estimatedheight and rowheight. As in my code, rowHeight is above then estimatedheight.